# How many records were obtained from the select statement in a variable?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, count

I use this code in stored procedure.
I want insert return value select statement into a variable like this :

```
declare @count int
set @count = select count(*) from table_name
```

Is it possible?
Please help

Comment: This will **heavily depend** on what actual, concrete **database system** (RDBMS) you're using - so please add a relevant tag to your question! Is it `mysql`? `postgresql` ? `oracle` ? `sql-server` ? `db2` ?

Comment: I wrote my stored procedure in with sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is if you wrap it in parentheses.

```
declare @count int
set @count = (select count(*) from table_name)
```

But it is simpler to just

```
declare @count int
select @count = count(*) from table_name
```

This works in SQL Server. YMMV